# Защита скрипта от распространения

Tags: скрипт, защита, php

Вот хочу поставить на продажу скрипт, но не знаю как защитить его от распространения другими лицами (платно или бесплатно). Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зашифруйте его с помощь Zend Guard. В код никто не сможет внести изменения, добавьте в скрипт привязку к домену (или в самом Zend Guard можно настроить привязку к домену) и никакого распространения не будет.

Единственный минус, не на всех хостингах может стоять zend optimizer (необходим для того чтобы зашифрованные файлы заработали), поскольку защифрованные скрипты могут создавать повышенную нагрузку, но это со слов хостинговой компании :)

Помимо Zend Guard существуют и другие программы: ionCube, Nu-Coder.

Есть также так нызываемые программы Дезендеры, которые призваны расшифровать байт код, но на практике работают они плохо и на выходе получается неработающий код.

Comment: Мда, жаль, что другого способа нет, Zend и ему подобные меня бесят, во-первых нужно дополнительная поддержка у хостинга, во вторых если какие-то изменени надо будет внести, покупатель не сможет. А привязка к домену не эффективна тем, что домен тоже может менятся.

Comment: zend optimizer практически везде есть

Comment: В любом другом варианте любую вашу проверку можно будет из скрипта удалить и несанкционированного его скопировать.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в код периодическую отправку на ваш сервер POST-запроса с токкеном покупателя. На своем сервере проверяйте соответствие токкена домену, указанному при покупке, и возвращайте ответ, в зависимости от которого код продолжит работать или выполнит некоторые действия (уведомит вас о левом использовании кода, вернет некорректные данные или внесет изменения в свой код).

Ответ при этом должен быть для непосвященных рандомный, но в самом коде должна быть проверка на валидность.

Comment: Эмм, и что если эту отправку и отключение скрипта в случае неудачи просто выпилят к чертям из скрипта?

Comment: При большом объеме кода это можно замаскировать. Вплоть до того, что добавить целые пласты фейкового кода. Который то ли исполняется, то ли нет. Есть предел сложности программы, после которой понять, что к чему фактически невозможно. Добавьте сюда испорченное форматирование, уберите комментарии, замените нормальные имена переменных на a1, b2, c3...

Comment: @Khvorostin, ну при большом объёме и +обфускация, да, но всё равно, докопаться хоть и очень трудно, но реально, если будет желающий...)

Comment: @Construct, вопрос в соотношении стоимости кода и требуемых усилиях.